# Yocto - Where is the most appropriate place to disable creation of /etc/hostname

Tags: yocto, systemd, hostname

When building core-image-minimal on poky (in my case this is being built for custom hardware loosely based on the BBG reference), yocto writes a hostname to /etc/hostname on the file system image.

Occasionally it is preferable to exclude the creation of the hostname file during the fs image build, and instead generate a hostname, and subsequently an /etc/hostname file, dynamically the first time a device boots the image.

An example implementation would be the employment of systemd and a 'firstboot' unit file that uses  *ConditionPathExists=|!/etc/hostname*  to determine the need to generate a hostname.

So, where is the most appropriate place/method for disabling the creation of /etc/hostname?

Answer (score 1):

You can change and define your own hostname, edit your local.conf:

```
hostname_pn-base-files = "your_hostname_here"
```

Comment: ...and to actually answer the question: If you define an empty hostname that way, the `/etc/hostname` isn't created. It is handled in `base-files` recipe in openembedded-core, you can check it there.

Comment: hostname_pn-base-files sets a hostname.  The requirement im facing is to NOT set a hostname.  Further, no /etc/hostname file should be created.
@TomasNovotny I may have misinterpreted you suggestion;  an empty hostname_pn-base-files will raise a parser exception.
The only reference to the hostname that I am aware of in core, is hostname.sh, which generates the /etc/hostname file if it doesnt exist.
Is the proposed option, patch the hostname.sh in my layer?

Comment: maybe just look at the [manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#usingpoky-extend-customimage-image-name)